# elasticsearch range aggregation with fixed buckets values

Tags: elasticsearch, range, fixed, aggregation

I need to create an aggregation, like "range" but I need to specify the "where" clause of each bucket.

For example if we aggregate on an "age" field, what range agg offer is:

- bucket 1: to 10
- bucket 2: from 10 to 50
- bucket 3: from 50

what I need is:

- bucket 1: [5,4334,211 and 76]
- bucket 2: [66 and 435]
- bucket 3: [5455, 7968, 1, 443 and 765]

I don't want to create 3 "terms" aggregations with the "include" property, what I need is one aggregation with 3 buckets (just like range offers).

Any ideas or alternatives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is another way of having a similar result using terms aggregation with scripting.

```
"aggs": {
"age_ranges": {
  "terms": {
    "script": {
      "inline": "if(ageMap.containsKey(doc['age'].value)){ageMap.get(doc['age'].value)} else {'<unmapped>'} ",
      "params": {
        "contentIdMapping": {
          "1": "bucket-3",
          "5": "bucket-1",
          "66": "bucket-2",
          "76": "bucket-1",
          "211": "bucket-1",
          "435": "bucket-2",
          "443": "bucket-3",
          "765": "bucket-3",
          "4334": "bucket-1",
          "5455": "bucket-3",
          "7968": "bucket-3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Only the first bucket would cause an issue since the range is discontinued, but all the other ones can be specified easily with a `from/to` constraint in `range` buckets. I suggest something like this:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "age_ranges" : {
            "range" : {
                "field" : "age",
                "ranges" : [
                    { "from": 5,  "to": 6 },     <--- only 5
                    { "from": 10, "to": 13 },    <--- 10, 11, 12
                    { "from": 13, "to": 15 },    <--- 13, 14
                    { "from": 20, "to": 26 }     <--- 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but this is not quite what I'm looking for. My example wasn't too good actually. The range could be a random group of ids actually.

what I need is:

 - bucket 1: [6567, 11192, 759845, 79685]
 - bucket 2: [55, 896858, 459858]
 - bucket 3: [689658,696958,70707]

Comment: Then, indeed, the example wasn't that good :-) Sorry about that